Outlook: Online Meeting Provider not found (MS Teams Integration does not work in Outlook although Addin installed successfully)
I want to use Teams within Outlook. So I want to add a Teams-Link in new appointments.
My Environment:

Windows 10 Pro
Microsoft 365 Subscripton (Familiy).
Microsoft Teams (Version: 24243.1309.3132.617. Indicated as most recent version of MS Teams)

What I already tried

I am currently successfully logged into my Microsoft Account.
I ran the Office Update to make sure every Office components are up to date
I deinstalled and downloaded most recent version of MS TEams and installed it successfully

What is the problem?
In Outlook I checked:
File -> Options -> Calendar and found there is not Online Meeting Provider available:

The selected account hannes_heckner@outlook.de is the correct Office 365 Account which is successfully setup (and displayed as MS Exchange Account)
I checked the Teams Addin under Com-Addins with
Files->Options->Addins:

Now I see this

"Anmelden" means login in english.
But when I click on the button the MS Teams Windows pops to front but nothing more happens. So the question is: Is there some functionality (like in my office that I can directly add a Teams Link to an appointment)
And still the online meeting provider dialog still shows no entries:


Are you using New Teams?
This appears to be a known issue from before, and the current status has been resolved.
Follow the steps in this document to install the add-in correctly.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/teams-meeting-add-in-is-missing-in-outlook-desktop-after-updating-to-new-teams-f1dfc3e7-8f48-4320-823b-e13a5aca60c3

Thanks for response. It seems that I have the most recent version:  24243.1309.3132.617.
And it is not (!) a matter of the add-in. This is installed perfectly well. It's more that the online meeting provider is emtpy. I'll update my description above to clarify this

This add-in can also be controlled by Teams admins. You try to create a meeting from Outlook and Teams on the web, and if neither works, start checking with the Teams policy.
